# Uso de Swing no java EE

Tags: java

Boa Tarde, quando o programador trabalha com java WEB, ele gera interface grafica  usando a classe javax.swing como em Desktop?

Comment: Até onde sei, swing é somente desktop, para web há o [JAVA FX](http://blog.caelum.com.br/falando-em-java-introducao-ao-javafx/).

Comment: Obrigado Diego..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

**Não,** quando se fala em Java Web, ainda mais em Java EE, as interfaces são construídas usando HTML, CSS e JavaScript.

Mas esta não é a história completa...

## Java Applets

Na verdade é possível em algum grau usar Swing numa página web usando Java Applets, que são programas Java que executam na máquina do usuário, dentro do navegador, e podem usar componentes Swing.

É como ter uma janela desktop dentro do navegador.

Porém, Java Applets é uma tecnologia defasada, que ninguém mais recomenda usar, inclusive o Chrome deixou de suportar há alguns meses. Os principais problemas são relacionados à segurança e também ao fato de que isso foge completamente ao conceito de um sistema web.

## [Java Network Launch Protocol (JNPL)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html)

Outra tecnologia que tenta facilitar o uso de aplicações Java Desktop é JNPL, que permite que uma aplicação desktop, possivelmente baseada em Swing, seja baixada e executada pelo usuário automaticamente, sem necessidade de instalação ou configuração.

Não é incomum sistemas web servirem de ponte para uma aplicação JNDI, isto é, você faz o login no sistema web e então é redirecionado para um descritor JNPL que então carrega sistema desktop na sua JVM local.

## Quase Swing [*#sqn*](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/sqn/)

Para aproveitar a familiaridade que muitos desenvolvedores tem do Swing, algumas soluções para Java Web tentam aproveitar o mesmo conceito de componentização, como é o caso do [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home), [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), GWT ou até JSF, embora este último esteja hoje um pouco mais próximo do HTML que os demais.

Basicamente eles usam algum template ou mesmo API que permite você construir e manipular componentes via código, entretanto esses componentes são implementados com HTML, CSS e JavaScript.

Alega-se que tal uso dos componentes aumenta a produtividade, já que o desenvolvedor não precisa se preocupar com o *design*. Entretanto, tais frameworks tem a fama de apresentarem diversas dificuldades para estender os componentes ou de compatibilidade com navegadores, fazendo com que muitas vezes o desenvolvedor tenha que cavar em scripts e tags em algum momento.

Comment: Obrigado pelo Comentario , Esclareceu Minha Duvida..